# Why would "pip freeze" print out packages that I did not install?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, python, pip

I have two Ubuntu 18 machines. In one machine, I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu, and I created a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env`. When I activate this environment using `source env/bin/activate` and then run `pip freeze`, it doesn't print anything out. This is what I would have expected, since I hadn't installed any Python packages for this virtual environment yet.

However, in the second machine, I have an older installation of Ubuntu, which is a bit messy and has lots of packages installed already. I also created a virtual environment and activated it, but when I run `pip freeze` here, it prints out a very large number of Python packages. This was surprising to me, because I thought that `pip freeze` prints out the Python packages that have already been installed in that environment; and in this case, I hadn't installed any Python packages. Furthermore, I then looked into the `site-packages` folder of the virtual environment, and it didn't contain any of these Python packages.

So my question is: What are some possible reasons why `pip freeze` is printing out all these packages, when I did not actually install them in the environment?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the -l or --local option to freeze only the local packages in the virtual environment (and not the global ones)

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```